# Orthogonal range reporting with fixed upper rectangular corner

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, computational-geometry

Consider the following special case of [orthogonal range searching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_searching#Orthogonal_range_searching):

Given a set $S$ of $n$ points in $d$ dimensions, and rectangular queries with a fixed "upper-left" rectangle corner $(0,0,...0)$, report the total number of points inside the rectangle.

This is different in that all rectangles queried have a fixed corner. In this case, will we have a dynamic algorithm with a better runtime, or is the problem still as hard as general orthogonal range searching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The count of any rectangle $C(U, L, D, R)$ can be obtained combining the counts of 4 fixed "upper-left" retangles:

$C(U, L, D, R) = C(0, 0, D, R) - C(0, 0, U, R) - C(U, 0, D, L) + C(0, 0, U, L)$,

noting $C(up, left, down, right)$ the count in the rectangle delimited by $(up, left, down, right)$.

Thus, you cannot expect more than a factor 4 runtime improvement.